# Finding covariance of $f_{(x,y)} (x,y) = \frac{1}{4}(y-x)e^{-y}$ for $-y<x<y$ and $y>0$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, covariance

Our joint density function is

$f_{(x,y)} (x,y) = \frac{1}{4}(y-x)e^{-y}$  for $-y<x<y$ and $y>0$ and 0 elsewhere.

I know $Cov(X,Y) = E(XY) -E(X)E(Y).$

But I get that E(X) is not finite:

$f_x(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} .25*(y-x)e^{-y}dy = \frac{1}{4}(1-x)$

$E(X)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x*\frac{1}{4}(1-x)dx$ which I got to diverge.

Where did I mess up or does the covariance not exist?

Comment: Shouldn'y it be $E(X)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} xf_X(x)dx$?

Comment: Oh yea, you're right

Comment: I think that $f_{X}(x)$ is actually $\int_{|x|}^\infty f(x, y)\, dy$, because the pdf is not supported for $y\le |x|$.

Comment: I thought because y's range is not dependent on x it should just go from 0 to infinity? Also @TitoEliatron even with the new range it still diverges?

Comment: @preferred_anon comment is a very good one. With it,Wilfaram MAtehmatica says $E(X)=1$.

Comment: @LTM There is no "x range" and "y range". The joint distribution has a domain, which consists of all $(x,y)$ such that $y > 0 $ *and* $ -y < x < y$. You may wish to draw it - it's a big triangle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula for marginal distribution should be $f_X(x) = \frac{1}{4}e^{-|x|}(|x|-x+1)$), but we don't need it. We can just use a double integral to compute all the moments from the the joint distribution:
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[X^m Y^n] 
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-y}}{4}x^m y^n (y-x) \left[|x| < y\right] \ dx \ dy \\
&= \int_{0}^\infty \int_{-y}^y \frac{e^{-y}}{4}x^m y^n (y-x)\ dx \ dy \\
&= \int_{0}^\infty \frac{y^n e^{-y}}{4} \int_{-y}^y (yx^m - x^{m+1}) dx \ dy \\
&= \int_{0}^\infty \frac{y^n e^{-y}}{4} \left. \left(\frac{yx^{m+1}}{m+1}-\frac{x^{m+2}}{m+2}\right) \right|_{-y}^y \ dy \\
&=  \left(\frac{1-(-1)^{m+1}}{m+1}-\frac{1-(-1)^{m+2}}{m+2}\right)  \int_{0}^\infty \frac{y^{n+m+2} e^{-y}}{4}  \ dy \\
&= \begin{cases} 
\frac{(m+n+2)!}{2(m+1)}& m \text{ even}\\
-\frac{(m+n+2)!}{2(m+2)} & m \text{ odd}\end{cases}
\end{aligned}
$$
Where we use $\int_{0}^\infty y^{n} e^{-y} \ dy =\Gamma(n+1) = n!$.
Hence
$$
\begin{aligned}
E[X] &= -\frac{3!}{2(3)} = -1 \\
E[Y] &= \frac{3!}{2(1)} = 3\\
E[XY] &= -\frac{4!}{2(3)} -4 \\
\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y) &= -4 - (-1)(3)=-1
\end{aligned}
$$